# How to utilize all available bandwidth with real-time data?

Tags: algorithm, network-programming, real-time, network-protocols, latency

How to measure actual bandwidth between server and client to decide how much of real-time data to send?

My server sends read-time data to clients, 30 times per second. If server has too much data it prioritises data chunks and throws away anything that doesn't fit into available bandwidth because this data will be invalidated next tick anyway. Data is sent over reliable (20%) and unreliable channels (80%) (both UDP based but if TCP as a reliable channel can provide any benefit please let me know). Data is highly latency-sensitive. Server often (but not always!) has more data than available bandwidth. It's critical to send as much data as possible but not more than available bandwidth to avoid packets drop or higher latency.

Server and client are custom applications so can implement any algorithm/protocol.

My main problem is how to keep track of available bandwidth. Also any statistical info about typical bandwidth jitter would be helpful (servers are in a cloud, clients are home users, worldwide).

At the moment I'm thinking how to utilize:

- latency info of reliable channel. It should correlate with bandwidth because if latency grows this can (!) mean retransmission is involved as result of packets drop and so server must lower data rate.
- data amount received by client on unreliable channel during time frame. Especially if data amount is lower than what was sent from server.
- if current latency is close to or below lowest recorded one, bandwidth can be increased

The problem is that this approach is too complicated and involves a lot of "heuristics" like what should be a step to increase/decrease bandwidth etc.

Looking for any advice from people who dealt with similar problem in the past or just any bright ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the problem has a name: Congestion Control, or Congestion Avoidance Algorithm. It's quite a complicated topic and there're lots of materials about it. [TCP Congestion Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm) was evolving over time and is really good one. There're other protocols that implement it, e.g. UDT or SCTP

Answer (score 1):

The first symptom of trying to use more bandwidth than you actually have will be increased latency, as you fill up the buffers between the sender and whatever the bottleneck is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat. My guess is that if you can successfully detect increased latency as you start to fill up the bandwidth and back off then you can avoid packet loss.

I wouldn't underestimate TCP - people have spent a lot of time tuning its congestion avoidance to get a reasonable amount of the available bandwidth while still being a good network citizen. It may not be easy to do better.

On the other hand, a lot will depend on the attitude of the intermediate nodes, which may treat UDP differently from TCP. You may find that under load they either prioritize or discard UDP. Also some networks, especially with satellite links, may use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_acceleration without you even knowing about it. (This was a painful surprise for us - we relied on the TCP connection failing and keep-alive to detect loss of connectivity. Unfortunately the TCP accelerator in use maintained a connection to us, pretending to be the far end, even when connectivity to the far end had in fact been lost).

Comment: do you have any info about typical bandwidth fluctuation? I mean in the middle, I understand the user watching youtube can cause massive bandwidth drop

Comment: No info. A quick search finds maps of latency - http://internethealthreport.com/ http://www.internettrafficreport.com/ https://www.dotcom-tools.com/internet-backbone-latency.aspx The people who really care may already have moved to co-location in e.g. stock trading centres so the best data may be proprietary and not representative of anybody else's problem.